# GWT setProperty with TransformOrigin

Tags: css, gwt, attributes

I would like to apply the following style to an element:

```
 style = "transform-origin: top left;"
```

I'd like to use in GWT

```
element.getStyle().setProperty("TransformOrigin", myValue);
```

where "myValue" is a String. Which value should take "myValue" to end up applying the "top left" attributes?

I can't find any documentation on the TransformOrigin property for GWT!

Comment: Don't forget to use the proper camel case string - "transformOrigin", not "TransformOrigin"! As far as the value goes, its the same as normal html - GWT doesn't change the value part at all.

Comment: It didn't work with "transformOrigin". I found the solution, so I'm putting it below in case someone needs it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works for all major browsers:

```
 String[] engines = new String[]{"","webkit","ms","Moz","O","khtml"};      
 String value = "0 0";
 String name = "TransformOrigin";
    for( String prefix : engines ) {
        element.getStyle().setProperty( prefix+name, value);
    }
```